# R quantmod package behaves differently when executed from console versus from TextMate

Tags: r, console, textmate

Here is the code:

```
require("quantmod")

getSymbols("GLD") 
getSymbols("SLV")
getSymbols("TLT")

GSR = GLD/SLV

par(mfrow=c(2,2))

chartSeries (GLD, subset="2010", TA = NULL)               
chartSeries (SLV, subset="2010", TA = NULL)               
chartSeries (TLT, subset="2010", TA = NULL)               
chartSeries (GSR, subset="2010", TA = NULL)
```

When I run this file from TextMate with the Command R keystroke, I get four charts lined up in a 2 x 2 grid, as you'd expect from the par() function. When I source this from the R console,

```
> source("~/myChartSeries.r")
```

I get a flash of each chart with the last one depicted alone. The last I'd heard, chartSeries() was not compliant with the par() function but chart_Series() is. So the behavior of the console is not surprising. But why does execution from TextMate work? Has chartSeries() been made par() compliant and is the R console execution flawed?

Comment: When I run that code in R I **do not** get four panels on a page regardless of whether I run the code directly in a console or from `source()`

Comment: Yes, in a console and with source() is the same thing. I should be more clear and say 'from console via the source() function.' The mystery is why it works when run from a text editor such as TextMate.

Comment: So your editor sets up a slightly different environment. Put your ass on your chair and start comparing.  Code is deterministic, and it **will be your local setup** that drives this.

Comment: Be nice.

Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you. We're all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.

Comment: *Put your ass on your chair* is a classic quote most of us who have been through grad school will have heard near the beginning of dissertation work.  This is similar: your code, your trading model, your debugging work.  You have to understand that we *still help you* when we point where not to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the code is run from TextMate, it prints all four charts separately with the 'illusion' that it is a single chart with four panels. In fact, when I comment out the par() function,

```
#par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

I get the same result. So it appears that chartSeries() is still not par() compliant.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me from either location:

```
layout(matrix(seq(4), nrow=2))

chartSeries (GLD, subset="2010", TA = NULL, layout=NULL)               
chartSeries (SLV, subset="2010", TA = NULL, layout=NULL)               
chartSeries (TLT, subset="2010", TA = NULL, layout=NULL)               
chartSeries (GSR, subset="2010", TA = NULL, layout=NULL)
```

Hope this helps.